# How do national union/employer negotiations work?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, labor-union, labor-policies

There are currently a number of high-profile nationwide strikes taking place (or planned) in the UK: teachers, nurses, firemen, railway workers and university lecturers, amongst others. In all cases, the primary dispute focuses on pay and conditions.

We often hear that 'negotiations are taking place' between union representatives and employers' representatives, lasting multiple days. Yet the focus of the dispute usually seems straightforward: the unions want a pay rise of X%, while the employers claim they can only afford to pay Y%.

A common factor in these disputes is that they involve many employers working to a nationally-agreed payscale -- so there is (I presume) limited flexibility to address local pain-points as 'sweeteners' to the deal ("OK, what if we increase pay by Y% *and* refurbish the bathrooms?").

So, what actually happens in the negotiation room? Do the two sides just spend days shouting their respective numbers at each other in the hope that one side gets bored? Do they agree to split the difference on the morning of day one, but string it out so that the members feel they 'fought a good fight'? Are there actually meaningful things that get discussed?

Comment: You seem misinformed. A lot of disputes have other factors. Railway workers are concerned about [job cuts and employment conditions as well as pay](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-61634959): ticket office closures, Sunday working, driver-only trains, changes to shift patterns, and many other things. I suggest you restrict your question to a particular dispute if you wish to know what the issues are.

Answer (score 8):

A major public sector employee's union (UNISON) in the U.K. [describes the process as follows at their website](https://www.unison.org.uk/about/what-we-do/negotiating-and-bargaining/):

> The aim of negotiation is to reach an agreement. Negotiation should
> not be confused with ‘consultation’, which is simply an exchange of
> opinions between workers and their employer. However, skilful
> negotiators can turn consultation into negotiation.
>
> Stewards do not normally negotiate alone, but as part of a team with
> complementary skills.
>
> To start the negotiation process, a UNISON rep or official may write
> to the employer to raise a claim. They then meet management to present
> the case.
>
> A series of meetings may follow to discuss the issue in depth. If you
> attend one of these meetings, it is as important to listen carefully
> and ask questions as it is to present your case well. Clear, effective
> communication during negotiation is important as it can help others to
> understand your point of view.
>
> The negotiation process tends to follow a standard pattern, which
> falls into four recognised stages.
>
> **Preparation**: You need to do careful preparation and research, especially in canvassing the views of your members.
>
> **The opening**: One side tables a proposal and the other side responds. This stage can involve adjournments to collect further
> information and test out arguments. It also includes identifying the
> relative importance of issues, fall-back positions and ‘bottom lines’.
>
> **Trading:** Both sides trade things in order to move from fixed opening positions to an agreement: “We’ll offer x if you’ll agree to
> y.” Again, there can be lots of adjournments to explore options, test
> arguments, consult, etc. This stage builds consensus and narrows down
> the areas of disagreement.
>
> **Agreement**: This should include a phase where the final proposal is put to the members and ends with the agreement being documented for
> future reference.
>
> To reach an agreement, both sides must be open to new ideas and
> willing to accept changes. If no agreement is made, negotiations can
> break down and unions may resort to industrial action. If industrial
> action is required, UNISON regional offices get involved and provide
> advice on the correct procedures to follow.
>
> Once workers and employers have reached an agreement, it is signed and
> kept in place either for a set time or until replaced.

One aspect of the negotiations that is understated above is the time spent getting everyone on the same page by restating the status quo and any relevant legal parameters to the negotiations, and by not really going into depth and detail regarding the substantial amount of justification and exchanges of information about the needs of workers, the employment marketplace, the ability of the employer to pay, and the credibility of a strike/lockout threat (and the ability of an employer to endure a sustained strike) that is involved in the opening and trading phases of the process.

Generally the parties don't simply immediately jump to a specific proposed change in contract terms. They go well beyond merely going through the motions to justify their stances with factual background in lengthy presentations and discussions, even if ultimately, the decision will come down to raw bargaining power. This could take as little as half a day to as long as several days in connection with the presentation of the opening at the outset. Similarly iterations of these kinds of presentations often follow as more specific sub-issues are addressed.

Often adjournments are to respond to information requests from the other side to back up claims initially made without justification in the course of the negotiations.

There is also, as the quoted material somewhat soft pedals, a lot of time spent waiting around and chatting while the ball is in the other side's court for the moment.

Sometimes the process involves direct face-to-face negotiations between representatives of the employer and the unions, and sometimes this is structured and facilitated by a professional labor mediator.

Comment: It might be worth noting that "adjournment" could mean that through a 12-hour negotiation day the two sides actually sit in the same room for maybe 4 hours. The rest of the time, they will meet in separate rooms to consider what they just heard and form strategies.

Comment: @ccprog You are correct.

Comment: This describes the formal negotiation process in great detail but as I understood OPs question they were wondering what topics are actually discussed. It seems like the only topic is the actual number of the raise so it is unclear why discussing this single number should take hours or days.

Comment: There are usually a lot more topics than just the pay. For example how the raises are to be distributed for low vs. high incomes, holidays, working hours, work from home options etc.

Comment: @quarague The point of this answer is that a lot of the discussions are about the justifications for a number. This often goes on for hours and hours discussing the subtopics mentioned.